# Define routing requirements in Symfony2 based on a range of numbers

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I'm playing around with a [symfony tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/routing.html#generating-urls) and I was wondering if and how I can use different routing based on the amount of a given wildcard in the URL-path.
Here is the code of my routing yaml:

```
app:
resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
type: annotation

luckynumberSmallNumbers:
    path:      /lucky/number/{max}
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Lucky:smallNumber, max: 10}
    requirements:
       max: \d+ #TODO: something to define numbers smaller  or equal to 10

luckynumberBigNumbers:
    path:      /lucky/number/{max}
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Lucky:bigNumber, max: 10}
    requirements:
        max: \d+ #TODO: something to define numbers greater than 10
```

So e.g. in my example the path would be /lucky/number/{max}
If the number given in {max} is greater than 10, another method/controller should be called than if the number is below or equal to 10.
How can I define this in the requirements for 10? I only found reqular expressions and I do not know how to bend those to my will :)
Find my repo here: https://github.com/mattlang88/first_symfony_project

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why don't you just check the value inside the Controller and act differently `if ($max > 10) { doThis(); } else { doThat(); }`? If you still consider using two routes, you could use Regular Expressions like `(10|[0-9]{1})` or whatever your requirements are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

requirements are regular expressions (regex), so you can have a regular expression like 
^([0-9]|10)$

for the second one you can define a regex for numbers bigger than 10 like this:
^0*([1-9]\d{2,}|0*[1-9]\d)$

Answer (score 1):

The requirements option accepts RegEx. so with [1-10] you could validate against a range